# Export array environment variable bash/bitbucket pipelines

Tags: bash, bitbucket-pipelines

I have the following variable in bitbucket deployment settings:

```
CALLBACKS="https://myapp.com" "http://localhost:3000"
```

I need to export it to an environment variable of type array that will be read by a script thereafter. I'm trying this but it's not working:

```
read -a CALLBACKS_ARRAY <<< "${CALLBACKS}"
export CALLBACKS_ARRAY="$(echo ${CALLBACKS_ARRAY})"
```

Comment: Arrays *cannot* be exported without being encoded/serialized. They're NUL-delimited, and environment variables can't contain NULs.

Comment: ...I'm assuming that bitbucket parses that variables in a manner equivalent to `CALLBACKS='https://myapp.com http://localhost:3000'`; otherwise, `read -a` wouldn't be behaving as you expect/intend.

Comment: (Keep in mind that the environment isn't a shell thing, it's a C thing; all environment variables are C strings -- that's true of exported functions too, which are just strings that the shell has special rules for deserializing; there are not presently any such special rules that deserialize environment variable contents into an array).

Answer (score 3):

**This cannot be done.** Environment variables are NUL-delimited; array definitions separate the items with NULs. Thus, you can only export an environment variable when it's serialized into a string, such that the child process can deserialize it into an array.

What you *can* do, by contrast, is export `BASH_ENV` with a filename containing content that, when sourced, will define your array.

Thus:

```
read -a CALLBACKS_ARRAY <<< "${CALLBACKS}"
BASH_ENV=$(mktemp -t bash_env.XXXXXX)
declare -p CALLBACKS_ARRAY >"$BASH_ENV"
export BASH_ENV
```

Note that a compliant `/bin/sh` reads `ENV` rather than `BASH_ENV`; that said, since arrays aren't present in the baseline POSIX sh standard, there's not much need to worry about that here.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this. May you tell me what the XXXXXX is for? Also, may I export multiple array variables this way?

Comment: The `XXXXXX` is placeholder characters that `mktemp` can replace to ensure that the filename is unique. Using unique temporary file names avoids symlink attacks.

Comment: And yes, you can run `declare -p name1 name2 name3 >"$BASH_ENV"` to write the definition of multiple variables to that file.